# RTTI и Наследование Delphi

Tags: delphi, rtti

Есть следующая иерархия классов

```
type
  TMainEntity = class(TUEntity)
  end;

  TUMining= class(TMainEntity)
  end;

  TUDistrict= class(TMainEntity)
  end;

  TModel = class(TUMining)
  public
    District: TUDistrict;
  end;
```

Но вот, при попытке получить информацию о классе, мне возвращает информацию о родителе.

```
var
  CurData: TObject;

CurData:= TModel.create;
LContext:= TRttiContext.Create;
LType:= LContext.GetType(CurData.ClassInfo);
LType.name == 'TUMining' // ПОЧЕМУ????
```

Проблема не в RTTI. При подготовке минимально воспроизводимого примера, проблема не обнаружена!

Так все предсказуемо и логично!

```
  var
    CurModel: TModel;
    CurData: TObject;

CurModel:= TModel.Create;
CurModel.District:= TUDistrict.create;
CurData:= CurModel;
```

Но используя конструкцию

```
CurModel:= TModel(CurNode.GetData^);
```

в упор передается `TUMining`. Хотя объект полноценно инициализирован!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как то так данные попадают в недра грида

```
type
  TEntityArray<T: TmainEntity, constructor> = array of T;

var
  ArrModel: TEntityArray<TModel>;
  ArrMining: TEntityArray<TUMining>;

ArrMining:= Adapter.FindAll;
ArrModel:= TEntityArray<TModel> (ArrMining);
ArrModel[i].District:= DistrictAdapter.Find('some_id');
InsertNode(nil,amInsertAfter,ArrModel[i]);
```

Comment: Потому что класс пустой, и компилятор видимо оптимизирует код - удаляет пустые "кластеры".

Comment: Попробуйте поиграть опциями компилятора. Что точно поможет - создайте процедуру и сделайте на неё ссылку, а лучше поставьте признак published (что б сгенерировать rtti, т.к. на остальные оно не генерируется).

Comment: сейчас попробую)

Comment: Попробовал ваш код у себя, в XE5 - все работает нормально. Имя класса TModel. Приведите минимальный воспроизводимый пример плиз.

Comment: @Kromster Сложновато будет, сейчас чего то придумаю, игры с компилятором и published не помогли

Comment: @Kromster Ошибка не с `RTTI` при подготовке минимально воспроизводимого примера ошибок не возникло(

Comment: что  увас в `CurNode.GetData` то по факту? Привести явно можно к чему угодно, но тип данных это не изменит и в таком случае исключения не вызовет.

Comment: @nick_n_a что-то вы перегнули про `published` и генерацию rtti.

Comment: `CurModel.District:= TUDistrict;` тут `create()` в конце забыт?

Comment: @teran, Да,спасибо подправил. И дополнил вопрос как и откуда берутся данные.

Comment: `ArrModel:= TEntityArray<TModel> (ArrMining);` это нормально, что `Mining` к `Model` приводится? из этих массивов у вас потом якобы криво возвращается тип? дак если `ArrMining` содержит экземпляры `TUMining` то хоть что делайте, они так ими и останутся, и в `TModel` не превратятся ни коим образом.

Comment: @teran Спасибо огромное, открыли глаза! Буду думать как избавится!)